# Calling RecyclerView within onBindViewHolder

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview

I set "setOnClickListener" within "OnBindViewHolder", so when I click an item, I'll do somethings.
But when I click an item, it gives an error like below,

```
 java.lang.IllegalStateException: holder.itemView.myAdsRecycleView must not be null
```

The line which gives error is below,

```
holder.itemView.myAdsRecycleView.layoutManager = myLinearLayout
```

What can be the problem? itemview and array seems doesn't null?

Full adapter codes are below,

```
class adsRecyleAdapter(var category:ArrayList<String>) : RecyclerView.Adapter<adsViewHolder>() {

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): adsViewHolder {
        var inflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.ads_menu_single_category_layout,parent,false)
        return adsViewHolder(inflater)
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return category.size
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: adsViewHolder, position: Int) {


        holder.itemView.txt_ads.text = category[position]


        holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(){


            if (holder.itemView.txt_ads.text.contains("Estate")){

                var array = holder.itemView.resources.getStringArray(R.array.realEstateCategory)
                var category_arraylist = ArrayList<String>(9)

                for (i in 0..4){
                    category_arraylist.add(array[i])
                }

                var myLinearLayout = LinearLayoutManager(holder.itemView.context, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL,false)
                holder.itemView.myAdsRecycleView.layoutManager = myLinearLayout

                var myadapter = adsRecyleAdapter(category_arraylist)
                holder.itemView.myAdsRecycleView.adapter = myadapter
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Also added holder code below,

```
class adsViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {
}
```

Itemview's codes are below,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".ads_category">

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/myAdsRecycleView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:background="@color/colorGray"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: you should do this myAdsRecycleView.layoutManager = myLinearLayoutManager

Comment: Bu I already made this with this line "holder.itemView.myAdsRecycleView.layoutManager = myLinearLayout".

Comment: Can we see the full code of your adapter please ?

Comment: sure, just added.

Comment: have you defined holder.itemView.myAdsRecycleView in holder?
it s better to paste holder code too. if you defined it so check imports to be done correctly to layout.

Comment: Just added holder class too.

Comment: Are you using the Android Kotlin Extensions? Please post your itemview xml as well.

Comment: @ge3ng  just added the xml codes.